# Dynamic inputs to Excel Solver

Tags: excel, solver

I am trying to create a solver model for a factory workcell that basically calculates the lowest cost manufacturing solution vs inventory (EOQ model) working within factory time constraints.
I have hit a blocker that some of the workcells consist of multiple line options that have different run rates and costs.
eg:
[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weWnD.png)
Basically, what I want to happen is for the WorkCentre used and therefore the associated costs and timings to update as the solver solves for the batch size.

I am not sure if this is possible for the excel solver...

Comment: Please provide more information about your model. For example: How is Setup Cost calculated? (is it `=IF(L2=1,J2/K2*F2,IF(L2=2,J2/K2*G2,""))`)? How is Inventory Holding cost calculated? ... The short answer is yes, but more information is needed to demonstrate how.

Comment: What's also confusing (to me, at least) are the words batch, demand, and lot - are these all the same units? For product a, using workcell 2, you show maximum batch size is 20000, the demand is 40000, and the lot size is 8000 - and you indicate the lot size is supposed to be changed by solver. This would mean the limit on lot size is 20000, and additional setup time/costs are incurred if I use lot sizes less than 20000. Correct?

Comment: The way you have it setup, you could only produce Product A in Workcell 1 OR Workcell 2. Do you want to be able to make some of the demand for Product A in Workcell 1 and some of the demand for Product A in Workcell 2?

Comment: As I understand, the OP is asking for inputs for whether the Excel solver can auto update its solution if some of the original criteria change. Is it so?